# How can I enable autoplay to work even when the screen is locked? 

Tags: multimedia

I have been setting up my machine to automatically rip a CD upon insertion and create a bunch of different formats.

So far this works great but I have noticed that the autoplay only works if I am logged into the desktop and the screen is unlocked.

Ideally I would like to be able to just throw a CD in the drive whenever I walk past the machine. Having to unlock the screen adds makes this operation take somewhat longer.

How can I enable autoplay to work even when the screen is locked?

Answer (score 0):

You don't. It's a really bad idea to let strangers run software on your desktop when you've locked it. Instead, deactivate screen lock.